# need help in tcl command usage for regsub

Tags: regex, tcl

I am new learner for `tcl`. I have some issue as below when using `regsub`. Consider the following scenario:

```
set test1 [list prefix_abc_3 abc_1 abc_2 AAA_0]

set test2 abc

regsub -all ${test2}_[1-9] $test1  [list] test1
```

I expected `$test1 output is [prefix_abc_3 AAA_0]`

However `regsub` has also removed the partial matched string which is `prefix_abc_3`. Does anyone here have any idea on how to regsub the exact words only in a list?

I tried to find solution via net but could not get any clue/hints. Appreciate if someone  here can help me.

Comment: Use backslashes before the [1-9] (yielding \\[1-9\\] ) because it will otherwise see 1-9 as a command to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[\m and \M](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M72) in regexps match the beginning and end of a word respectively. But you don't have a string of words in `test1`, but a list of elements, and sometimes there's a difference so don't mix the two. `regsub` only handles strings while [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm) works with lists:

```
set test1 [list prefix_abc_3 abc_1 abc_2 AAA_0]
set test2 abc
set test1 [lsearch -all -inline -not -regexp $test1 "^${test2}_\[1-9\]\$"]
```

If the pattern is that simple, you can use the `-glob` option (the default) instead of `-regexp` and maybe save some processor time.

Comment: You have solved my doubt. thanks for enlightened me, Potrzebie. Appreciated a lot :)

Comment: In 8.6: `lmap element $test1 {regsub $test2 $element ""}`

Answer (score 0):

What *exactly* did you execute?

When I type the commands above into `tclsh`, it displays an error -

```
% set test1 [list prefix_abc_3 abc_1 abc_2 AAA_0]
prefix_abc_3 abc_1 abc_2 AAA_0
% set test2 abc
abc
% regsub -all ${test2}_[1-9] [list] test1
invalid command name "1-9"
```

I'm unsure what you are trying to do. You start by inisitalising `test1` as a *list*. You then treat it as a *string* by passing it to regsub. This is a completely legal thing to do, but may indicate that you are confused by something. Are you trying to test your substitution by applying it four times, to each of `prefix_abc_3`, `abc_1`, `abc_2` and `AAA_0`? You can certainly do that the way you are, but a more natural way would be to do

```
foreach test $test1 {
    regsub $pattern $test [list] testResult
    puts stdout $testResult
}
```

Then again, what are you trying to achieve with your substitution? It looks as though your are trying to replace the string`abc` with a null string, i.e. remove it altogether. Passing `[list]` as a null string is perfectly valid, but again *may* indicate confusion between lists and strings.

To achieve the result you want, all you need to do is add a leading space to your pattern, pass a space as the substitution string and escape the square brackets, i.e.

```
regsub -all " ${test2}_\[-9\]" $test1 " " test1
```

but I suspect that this is a made-up example and you're really trying to do something slightly different.

**Edit**

To obtain a list that contains just those list entries that don't exactly match your pattern, I suggest

```
proc removeExactMatches {input} {
    set result [list];       # Initialise the result list
    foreach inputElement $input {
        if {![regexp {^abc_[0-9]$} $inputElement]} {
            lappend result $inputElement
        }
    }
    return $result
}

set test1 [removeExactMatches [list prefix_abc_3 abc_1 abc_2 AAA_0]]
```

Notes:

i)    I don't use regsub at all.

ii)   Although it's safe and legal to switch around between lists and strings, it all takes time and it obscures what I'm tryng to do, so I avoid it wherever possible. You seem to have a list of strings and you want to remove some of them, so that's what I use in my suggested solution. The regular expression commands in Tcl handle *strings* so I pass them strings.

iii)  To ensure that the list elements match exactly, I anchor the pattern to the start and end of the string that I'm matching against using `^` and `$`.

iv)   To prevent the interpreter from recognising the [1-9] in the regular expression pattern and trying to execute a (non-existant) command `1-9`, I enclose the whole pattern string within curly brackets.

v)    For greater generality, I might want to pass the pattern to the proc as well as the input list (of strings), in that case, I'd do

```
proc removeExactMatches {inputPattern input} {
    .
    .
    .
    set pattern "^"
    append pattern $inputPattern
    append pattern "\$"
    .
    .
    .
        if {![regub $pattern $inputElement]} {
        .
        .
        .
}

set test1 [removeExactMatches {abc_[1-9]} {prefix_abc_3 abc_1 abc_2 AAA_0}]
```

to minimise the number of characters that had to be escaped. (Actually I probably wouldn't use the quotation marks for the start and end anchors within the `proc` - they aren't really needed and I'm a lazy typist!)

Looking at your original question, it seems that you might want to vary only the `abc` part of the pattern, in which case you might want to just pass that to your `proc` and append the `_[0-9]` as well as the anchors within it - don't forget to escape the square brackets or use curly brackets if you go down this route.

Comment: Hi Nurdglaw, 
Thanks for looking into my doubt. actually you have missed out a $test in the regsub command, that the reason it flagged the error.
 
your trial command % regsub -all ${test2}_[1-9] <missed $test1 here> [list] test1

Comment: Your foreach example is one of the way to replace but they might not able to produce the output that i looking for because they will replace  the any pattern that match abc_<number> to null. and what i try to do is replace the whole match exact string abc_<num> only. 

below is showing what i expect to get from the result
before: test1 is a list [prefix_abc_1 abc_1 abc_0 abc_6 def] with llength = 5
after:  test1 is a list with [prefix_abc_1 def] with llength = 2

hope this will make you clear on my question. thanks :)